# How to allow Domain Group access to IIS Virtual Directory (Remote Directory)

Tags: iis, network-share, virtual-directory

I am trying to configure a virtual directory in Internet Information Services, this virtual directory exposes a shared folder that is on a different server.
For example, IIS is on Server A and the shared folder is on Server B. However, the IIS website needs to be accessed by members of a domain group, when i try the below configurations, the users are not able to access the virtual directory from their own PCs. They get a credentials prompt and then they are not authorized when they enter their own username/password. The prompt just keeps resetting.

I have granted access to the domain group on the shared folder security settings with full access and privileges. But within IIS, when configuring the "Connect As" setting for the VD, I have tried a Specific User (App pool user) and the application user (pass-through authentication). Still, the users within my domain group are not able to access the files within the shared folder, they get a prompt to enter their username and password, but once they do they are not authenticated or authorized. It's worth noting that I have done the exact same configuration for a virtual directory for a folder that is LOCAL on Server A (IIS server) and the users are able to access it successfully, only when the VD is on a remote server does this issue occur. What's incorrect in my configuration ?
I Windows Authentication and Shared folders permissions enough for this kind of configuration ?

Comment: The domain user account used for the application pool needs to be configured for delegation. Has that been completed?  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/my-kerberos-checklist-8230/ba-p/316160